# Choropleth map scale and legend

Tags: d3.js, choropleth

Let me preface this by saying I am brand new to D3.js and coding in general. I am an infographic artist and I've been using QGIS to generate maps, but am trying to use D3.js to generate a choropleth map for a story about Opioid deaths. Basically I am trying to recreate this map.
[map from the Economist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKv1F.png)

I have tried to start by using this [map](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606) by Mike Bostock and changing some of the parameters but am getting stuck with the color range and scale. The measurement is 1 per 100,000 population. I have a domain that starts at 1.543385761 and ends at 131.0814217.

The code I'm struggling with is around the scale input and output:

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 132])
    .rangeRound([600, 860]);

var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain(d3.range(2, 10))
    .range(d3.schemeBlues[9]);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "key")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, 40)");

g.selectAll("rect")
  .data(color.range().map(function(d) {
      d = color.invertExtent(d);
      if (d[0] == null) d[0] = x.domain()[0];
      if (d[1] == null) d[1] = x.domain()[1];
      return d;
    }))
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("height", 8)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d[1]) - x(d[0]); })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d[0]); });
```

I can see that I need some bit of code that will define everything 25 and over as the darkest color. Not even sure I want that to be my final legend but I'd love to know how to reproduce that. I am shocked I was able to get this far but feel a bit lost right now. thank you in advance!

Comment: I found a few examples here: https://d3-geomap.github.io/map/choropleth/us-states/ and here: https://plot.ly/javascript/choropleth-maps/

Comment: Check out their website for the official documentation on it. https://d3js.org/ . Honestly, huge part of the software developing is just knowing how to google and finding a solution to the problem...not all of it but most.

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine your scale:

```
var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain(d3.range(2, 10))
    .range(d3.schemeBlues[9]);
```

Your domain is an array of created like so:

```
d3.range(2,10) // [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

These are your thresholds, colors will be mapped based on values that are less than or equal to 2, more than two up to three, more than three and up to four .... and over 9. This domain is mapped to nine values defined in the range:

```
d3.schemeBlues[9] // ["#f7fbff",  "#deebf7",  "#c6dbef",  "#9ecae1",  #6baed6",  #4292c6",  "#2171b5",  "#08519c",  "#08306b"]
```

To set the thresholds for those colors so that values over 25 are one color, define the domain with array that has the appropriate threshold(s):

```
.domain([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,25]);
```

In the snippet below, this domain is applied. Rectangles have colors dependent on their location, all rectangles after the 25th (count left to right then line by line) one will be of one color.

```js
var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,25])
    .range(d3.schemeBlues[9]);
    
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",500)
  .attr("height",500);
  
var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(d3.range(100))
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width",15)
  .attr("height", 15)
  .attr("y", function(d,i) { return Math.floor(i / 10) * 20 + 10 })
  .attr("x", function(d,i) { return i % 10 * 20 })
  .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d); })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Andrew....this definitely got me further but not completely where I need to be. Part of my confusion is in how the domain relates to the range and how that gets handed off to the key. In the Economist example they go in increments of 5 up until 25 (so 6 steps of color for schemeBlues...[6]). I got that part working but it appears I'm missing some counties that are in the dataset but not showing up on the map (seems a threshold issue?). I'm also unsure what the code starting at "var rects" is doing but I can't seem to plug that into my map code without breaking it.

Comment: The rects were just to visually demonstrate the scale - as I don't have your data to display on  a map. A threshold scale with thresholds (domain) 5,10,15,20,25, has six steps as you note, so if your range has six valid colors, any numerical value should be mapped to the appropriate color. If certain counties do get colored correctly, it can  be because not all counties have data, not all county ids line up with the geographic feature ids, or the data field you are using doesn't contain all numerical values. If you link to the data It would help (if need be, you could randomize it)

Comment: I can't attach CSV but here's the first bunch of rows: 
id,deaths
1003,9.817926552
1009,20.8069634
1073,21.50319444
1097,6.259102782
1117,5.270395232
2020,14.06116607
2122,22.39101604
2170,10.88085464
4003,19.77425708
4005,8.627073194

Comment: It's subtle, I found the potential error (maybe?) while randomizing the whole dataset in the example set - I lost a bunch of counties too. Take a look at the first county ID you reference: `1003` and compare to the .tsv in the example: `01003`. Excel and leading zeros...

Comment: so you think if I add in leading zeros it might fix it?

Comment: With only four digits, it won't match the county code in the geographic features, and therefore won't draw. You could try it for 1003, which is right in the middle of Alabama.

Comment: When I open the original .tsv in Excel the leading zeros aren't in there either.

Comment: Excel removes them automatically (which is always frustrating) - it assumes its a number field and erases the zeros. You need to set it as a text field so that it does not erase it.

Comment: You can fix this with script - see [this block](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/8c89a91ee3cf1b082e00c4463a75fc2e) - when loading the data with `.defer(d3.csv, "data.csv",`, I add a leading zero to each county that doesn't have a five digit id.

Comment: Well I fixed the leading zeros but it looks like that didn't fix some of the missing counties (nothing from California shows up)...but now I am questioning the original data set and looking for a new data source.

Comment: Thank you so much for that! I managed to fix the data (the trick is adding the leading zeros in a text editor and staying out of Excel) and also double checked by generating maps in QGIS. Now my next quandary is where to adjust the width of the key which is coming in compressed/narrower.